# Ember error in computed model property

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have the following Ember model for users, which contains a list of permissions:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    username: DS.attr(),
    permissions: DS.attr(), //e.g. ['edit', 'read']

    isEditor: function() {
        var perms = this.get('permissions');
        return perms.indexOf('edit') > -1;
    }.property('permissions')
});
```

I use this, amongst other things, to get a list of editors in a controller (for use in a `select`).  When I load the page, I get this error in the console:

```
Error: Something you did caused a view to re-render after it rendered but before it was inserted into the DOM.
```

It happened after adding the `isEditor` function, and if I comment out the contents of the function it works fine, although obviously the list I'm generating from it is incorrect.  But as far as I can see there is nothing wrong with the code.

**Edit:** I'm using the function in a controller mixin:

```
App.EditorsMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
    editors: function() {
        return this.store.filter('user', function(model) {
            return model.get('isEditor');
        });
    }.property()
});
```

**Edit 2:** It seems that the problem might be related to the fact that not all `store.find('user')` promises are fulfilled when `editors` is called.  Adding in a few `console.log` lines and running it though the debugger, I can see that I need something like this:

```
    editors: function() {
        this.store.find('user').then(function() {            
            return this.store.filter('user', function(model) {
                return model.get('isEditor');
            });
        });
    }.property()
```

But I can't figure out how to get a list of editors out of the mess of nested promises.

Comment: I doubt it's that code at all, probably the template using it, would you mind including that?  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/940/edit

Comment: My full code is way to complicated to paste into a bin, and of course I now can't get a small example fail!  Sometimes I get `TypeError: perms is undefined` before the other error though.  Is there a sensible way to debug this sort of issue?  All I can think of is comment out blocks until I find something that makes a difference but that's not really ideal.

Comment: returning a promise to a computed property is never ideal, because generally you get a computed property, and not a actual record/collection.  The example above isn't returning the find promise, so that definitely wouldn't work ;)  In your case, if you want users to be found before a particular controller is used, it'd be best to do that in the router on one of the model hooks (beforeModel, model, afterModel).  All of those hooks will block if a promise is returned to them until it's complete.  I still wouldn't recommend that. I'd try and fix the underlying problem.

Comment: Commenting out seems like the simplest way to find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, and I was on totally the wrong track.  It was simply that the `filter` function is run every time a record is changed, and some of those times are before all fields are populated.  Once that bombs out, the rest follows.  So the solution was just to check if `perms` is defined before using it:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    username: DS.attr(),
    permissions: DS.attr(), //e.g. ['edit', 'read']

    isEditor: function() {
        var perms = this.get('permissions');
        if (perms)
            return perms.indexOf('edit') > -1;
        else
            return false;
    }.property('permissions')
});
```

The somewhat cryptic errors from ember didn't help, but once I started to focus on the `TypeError` is became a lot clearer.